# Code "delete my account" button

Tags: vb.net, button

Im using vb 2013. I tried to code my delete button after adding SQL delete in my Database. I wrote code in the class (I called it userFunc) calling the SQL DeleteItYourself with the variable DeleteIt. I created button with the toolbox and double clicked it, now I'm lost. I have session in the Login button to make sure it presents the user nickname. I redirected it to the homepage when the "I want to delete my account" located. Iactually don't know what to do with the button. I want it to call the function DeleteIt, but before the function Delete I want it to ask the user with some pop up alert if he's sure. Any ideas how to code my button?
(I'm a high school student and it's my project, they don't ACTUALLY teach us Java, unfortunately... They tell us to copy paste and try to understand)

Comment: just a side tip: in the database add a column "deleted" and put it to true or false, don't drop users permanently. Second: your question should be a question and it could use some reformatting.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a starting point:

```
If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete your account? This cannot be undone.", _
    (MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel), _
    "Confirm Account Deletion") = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then

    UserFunc(DeleteIt)
End If
```

[MsgBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx) displays a message box to the user, waits for a response, and returns the value of the button pressed. In the code above, the three arguments are:

1. The message to display
2. The style of the message box. Note how these are numeric values and can be added.
3. The title of the window.